# How to test init.gradle script?

Tags: gradle, initialization, build.gradle

How can we write unit tests for init.gradle script ? any direction on this, would be great

We already have some gradle projects to run and test, before we deploy init.gradle to prod. But we need some more testing in terms of what if any API calls returns 500 errors or similar kind of test scenarios

Comment: I don't really understand your question? Scripts like `init.gradle` may interact with so many external systems so it cannot be unit tested at all. You may create some automated tests that check whether some files got created, but that would not be real unit tests. You also wrote *deploy init.gradle to prod*? What do you mean by this?